# Linux root partition filling up

Tags: linux, storage

I have desktop machine acting as a server for my home network (Ubuntu 20.04).  In recent weeks, df reports the percentage of disk usage rapidly increasing, up to 100% in a few days (the rate of disk usage has been accelerating).  The numbers that du reports do not increase and hence do not add up to the percent in use according to df.

When I reboot the machine, the disk usage is down around 60% (around 60 GB out of 110).

I wonder if my machine has been rooted and a hidden process is using my disk surreptitiously.  I installed and ran chkrootkit, but saw nothing suspicious.

Any help would be appreciated.  I've never seen this behavior before.  Please let me know what additional information would be helpful.

Comment: Disappears when you reboot?  Look in `/tmp`.  Another place to examine is `/var/log`.  Run this command to find the largest directories: `sudo du -xcd2 / | sort -nr | head -n20`.  Once you find one, run that same command, with the new directory of interest.

Comment: Also, run `sudo lsof +L1` to find files that have been deleted while still open: they will be accessible only by the process(es) holding them open, but still present until the process(es) close them, or die. That might also explain why the disk usage goes down on reboot. An improperly set up log file rotation for a custom service is a pretty common cause of these.